# How to group threads to be run by each executor thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadgroup

I have a requirement in Java where let’s say I have multiple bankAccountId’s and there could be multiple threads working on each bankAccountId at a time. I have to make sure that only one thread should act on a bankAccountId at a time but at the same time other threads can work on different bankAccountId. I am currently using executor service to run a fixed amount of thread pool.

I tried using semaphore and thread group but there doesn’t seems to be a direct way of assigning thread groups to executor service

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to make sure that only one thread should act on a bankAccountId at a time

The obvious way to do that would be to have threads `synchronized` on some lock object that is associated with an account whenever they are doing something to the account that should only be allowed by one thread at a time.

> I tried using semaphore...

That's classic. You don't often see `Semaphore` used for mutual exclusion today—we normally use something called "mutex" or [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)—but once upon a time, it was quite common. Typically one would use a *binary* semaphore for that purpose. That is, a `Semaphore` whose [`availablePermits`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#availablePermits()) is only ever allowed to be `1` or `0`.

**Q:** You say you "tried." Perhaps you could update your answer to say what happened when you tried, and why it wasn't satisfactory.

---

The rest of this probably won't help you solve your problem, but since you asked...

> ...and thread group

It's unclear to me how [`ThreadGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) would be of any help. `ThreadGroup` has a lot of deprecated methods these days. Probably the most useful of the methods that are left is the one that allows your program to [`interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#interrupt()) all of the threads in the group with a single method call.

> there doesn’t seems to be a direct way of assigning thread groups to executor service

A `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses a [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) to create its worker threads, and you can provide your own `ThreadFactory` instance when you [construct the executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)). Your thread factory can assign the new threads to whatever `ThreadGroup`, set their priorities, or do whatever else you want to do to them before it hands them over to the executor service.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario seems similar as mentioned in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631561/allowing-a-single-thread-to-use-a-long-value/76737843#76737843)

Multiple threads can work in parallel without stepping on other thread’s bankAccountId